# FCM support when app is terminated

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM notification for my app. When my app is in background or foreground I am receiving notification. But when my app is terminated that means closed from task then I am not receiving any notification. I searched about this and I am confused is it work when the app is terminated? I just need to know is it work or not when the app is terminated.

If it works when the app is terminated then I will go for next step for my app otherwise I will stop my implementation that's why I am not sharing any code. I followed [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive)

Answer (score 1):

Beware with fcm on iOS, there are 2 ways of sending and receiving data; one is upstream/downstream messages the other is the push notifications. If you are using upstream/downstream messages the fcm connection is closed after the app is suspended, new messages will not wake your app. You may use push notifications instead but of course the downside is that they are push notifications you don't have much control over them.

Comment: Then if I use firebase push notification when app is terminated then is it possible to send data from my app after receiving notification.

Comment: not really, if your app is terminated you won't be able to send data through fcm bc your app will not become active.